# Brand New WD Elements 1 TB External HDD not detected at all

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I just bought a WD Elements 1 TB External HDD from Amazon. But it doesn't seem to be detected. It is both compatible with USB-3.0 and USB-2.0. At-least that's what they claim. Following are the details of my Laptop

Dell Inspiron N5110
Intel Core i5-2450M CPU @2.50 GHZ

O.S: Windows 7 Home Basic SP1 (64 bits)

I had checked for all possible solution since last several hours. But didn't find anything to get my problem fixed. I had tried to connect it to another computer with Windows 7 professional, it was not reorganized in that as well.

The raw device is not even listed in my Disk Management. So I think the HDD delivered to me is either faulty or the USB cable is having some problem.

[Screenshot of my Disk Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br2AR.jpg)

Comment: Did you do any troubleshooting like connecting something else in the same USB port or trying your drive on another machine?

Comment: I don't think my USB is having any issues, because I am using the same to connect my smartphones and other data cards, pendrives and even a WD external HDD of one of my colleagues couple of days back. And I did tried to connect it to another Dell Laptop, but got the same result.

Comment: Then you should probably contact the seller for warranty support.

Comment: This HDD has a u-A USB3 connector. Some of these connectors are flimsy and frequently break traces between the connector and PCB. Open up the enclosure and check either if the connector is dead, or try the 1tB HDD in some SATA system if it is functional. Did you try different cables? Did you try a USB2-only cable?

Comment: The device is faulty. Their support confirmed just now. I have already ordered a replacement.  Thanks for your response though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Desktop or the Portable version of WD Elements? 
Can you feel the drive spinning when you plug it into the laptop? Does the LED of the drive turn on when you plug it in? IS the drive visible in the BIOS or in the Device Manager?

Try using other USB cables different from the one that came with your drive.
Download and run [WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostic](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=PvSmQX) and see if the application detects the device and if it does run both the quick and the extended tests and see if the drive passes them.

Try other ports where you know other such drives work. In order to exclude not enough power I'd try a powered USB hub and see if the drive works there.

Another thing you could try is boot a Linux Distro and see if this is a OS issue.

If the drive is indeed malfunctioning contact the seller or [our live support](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=6KgL8V) and proceed with the RMA procedure.

Comment: The device is faulty. Their support confirmed just now. I have already ordered a replacement. Thanks for all your response. :)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Make sure you keep backups of your data on multiple places in the future as such issues do happen for one reason or another.